# Regarding dereferencing a pointer while using in linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

Here I have tried to create a linked list and create a function which adds any given number to the staring of the linked list.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
struct Node* head=NULL;

void Add(int n){
    head=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    head->data=n;
    head->next=NULL;
    return;
}
```

Now my doubt is, here we have defined `head` to be a pointer variable of datatype `struct Node`. In `Add` function, we have assigned the address of new memory allocated to `head` pointer variable.

But when we are writing `head->data=n`, why are we not dereferencing `head` first, since `head` was a pointer variable, so it stores address, and to store variables like data, why shouldn't it be `*head->data`? Similar for `*head->next=NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator `->` is already a dereferencing operator. `head->data` is equivalent to `(*head).data`.

Comment: No need to add a "thank you" comment. Just mark the answer, after some time has passed; there might come better answers. ;-) Welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you need to do the addition in two steps. First create the new node and initialize it, and then link it to the list.  Or you will lose the whole list, as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head = NULL;

void Add(int n)
{

    // create the node.
    struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);  /* better */

    // then initialize it.
    node->data=n;

    // now you can link it to the list
    node->next=head; // this must be done before touching header, so we don't lose header's value.
    head = node;

}
```

By the way, don't cast the value returned by `malloc()`, that will lead you to bugs you will not wish in your code.  If you forget to `#include <stdlib.h>` you can run into serious *Undefined Behaviour* (more in 64bit systems, where a pointer and an integer have different sizes)  The cast tells the compiler you know what you are doing, so you will probably silence warnings and messages from the compiler that would be appreciated to get to the problem solution. Don't do it, it's not necessary since a lot of time ago (from the time of the first version of STD-C publication)